# Whole site overlay div?

Tags: javascript, css, z-index

I'm using this snippet to append an overlay to a whole site:

```
$(function() {

   var docHeight = $(document).height();

   $("body").append("<div id='overlay'></div>");

   $("#overlay")
      .height(docHeight)
      .css({
         'opacity' : 0.4,
         'position': 'absolute',
         'top': 0,
         'left': 0,
         'background-color': 'black',
         'width': '100%',
         'z-index': 5000
      });

});
```

It works great, only I need one element to sit above this overlay ID. I've given that element a z-index greater than the 5000 here, but it never seems to ascend above the gray overlay---any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to create a modal dialog? If that is the case instead of doing two div's add one div with content and have gray background to it filling the entire doc.

Comment: Could you show us all of the css rules for the element you want to put on top?  Have you tried using position:relative?  Does this happen in all browsers, or just one?

Comment: Keep in mind that an elements z-index can never exceed that of its parent.

Comment: having the code of that element you are trying to put on top of your overlay would help discern the problem

Answer (score 1):

Make sure it's a sibling and direct child of `body` to guarantee it'll work in IE along with giving it a `position` of anything other than `static` and a higher `z-index` than 5000.

Answer (score 0):

Give it `position:absolute` too, or `position:relative`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the element you want overlaying is positioned (like absolute or relative).. other wise z-index means nothing

Answer (score 0):

1st check where exactly the 2nd element is being added in other words if ur assigning this value in JQuery but ur using plain css to code the 2nd elements values there may be a confliction. Also u should try using some quotes where ur values are i found that using double quotes with opacity values help.

Just a suggestion though instead of trying to dynamically assign elements using JQuery and give them properties might i suggest u try plain css when giving the elements attributes and only use JQuery to manipulate what needs to be calculated and or cannot be accomplished by css alone. Then ur code would be like this:

```
$(function() {

   var docHeight = $(document).height();

   $("body").append("<div id='overlay'></div>");
   $("#overlay").height(docHeight);
   $("#overlay").css({"opacity":"0.4"});
});
```

and the element would also have the properties assigned by the default css file